# I need help adding legend functionality to my graph using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, visualization

The goal of this assignment is create an interactive visualization. I am making a bar graph that includes a legend to toggle certain bars.

The y-axis of my graph shows the number of electric car sales in Europe, the x-axis shows the country. The colors of the graph represent the range of the population for that country. I want to create a legend that, when a specific color is clicked, toggles the bars with that corresponding color.

This my first time ever using D3 so my code may or may not be up to par. Any help is appreciated!

```js
var salesData;
var runningData;
var runningColors;

var customLegendData = [{
    label: "Population: >10 Million",
    color: "#008B8B"
  },
  {
    label: "Population: 10 Million - 50 Million",
    color: "#2F4F4F"
  },
  {
    label: "Population: 50 Million - 100 Million",
    color: "#48308B"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  Plot();
  addCustomLegend(customLegendData);
  attachLegendToggle();
});

function Plot() {
  TransformChartData(chartData, chartOptions);
  BuildBar("chart", chartData, chartOptions);
}

function BuildBar(id, chartData, options, level) {
  var chart = d3.select("#" + id);

  var margin = {
      top: 10,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 70,
      left: 70
    },
    barWidth = 70,
    barPadding = 5;
  var width = (barWidth + barPadding) * runningData.length; // Adjusted the width
  var height = $(chart[0]).outerHeight() - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var xVarName;
  var yVarName = options[0].yaxis;

  xVarName = options[0].xaxis;

  var xAry = runningData.map(function(el) {
    return el[xVarName];
  });

  var yAry = runningData.map(function(el) {
    return el[yVarName];
  });

  var capAry = runningData.map(function(el) {
    return el.caption;
  });

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(xAry).rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

  var yMax = d3.max(runningData, function(d) {
    return +d[yVarName];
  });
  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, yMax]).range([height, 0]);

  var rcolor = d3.scale.ordinal().range(runningColors);

  chart = chart
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var bars = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(runningData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "bar " + d[xVarName]; // Add a class based on the country
    })
    .attr("data-country", function(d) {
      return d[xVarName]; // Add data attribute with the country name
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (x(d[xVarName]) + barPadding / 2) + ", 0)";
    });

  var ctrtxt = 0;

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(xAry.length)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      var mapper = options[0].captions[0];
      return mapper[d];
    });

  var yAxisTicks = [0, 10000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000]
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickValues(yAxisTicks);

  bars.append("rect")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "bar-" + d[xVarName]; // Add a class based on the country
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(parseInt(d[yVarName]));
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(parseInt(d[yVarName]));
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - barPadding)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return rcolor(d[xVarName]);
    });

  bars.append("text")
    .attr("x", x.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(parseInt(d[yVarName])) - 5;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d[yVarName];
    })
    .attr("class", "bar-text");

  chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

  chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", -40)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

  return chart;
}

function attachLegendToggle() {
  d3.selectAll("#legend .legend-item").on("click", function(event, d) {
    var country = d.label;
    var barsToToggle = d3.selectAll("#chart [data-country='" + country + "']");

    barsToToggle.classed("hidden", function() {
      var isHidden = d3.select(this).classed("hidden");
      return !isHidden;
    });
  });
}

function TransformChartData(chartData, opts, level, filter) {
  var result = [];
  var resultColors = [];
  var counter = 0;
  var hasMatch;
  var xVarName;
  var yVarName = opts[0].yaxis;

  xVarName = opts[0].xaxis;

  for (var i in chartData) {
    hasMatch = false;
    for (var index = 0; index < result.length; ++index) {
      var data = result[index];

      if (data[xVarName] == chartData[i][xVarName]) {
        result[index][yVarName] = result[index][yVarName] + chartData[i][yVarName];
        hasMatch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (hasMatch == false) {
      ditem = {};
      ditem[xVarName] = chartData[i][xVarName];
      ditem[yVarName] = chartData[i][yVarName];
      ditem["caption"] = opts[0].captions != undefined ? opts[0].captions[0]
        [chartData[i][xVarName]] : "";
      ditem["title"] = opts[0].captions != undefined ? opts[0].captions[0]
        [chartData[i][xVarName]] : "";
      ditem["op"] = 1;
      result.push(ditem);

      resultColors[counter] = opts[0].color != undefined ? opts[0].color[0]
        [chartData[i][xVarName]] : "";

      counter += 1;
    }
  }
  runningData = result;
  runningColors = resultColors;
  return;
}


var chartData = [{
    "Country": "UK",
    "Sales": "370000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "France",
    "Sales": "340000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Norway",
    "Sales": "166000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Sweden",
    "Sales": "163000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Italy",
    "Sales": "114000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Netherlands",
    "Sales": "107000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Belgium",
    "Sales": "97000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Spain",
    "Sales": "82000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Switzerland",
    "Sales": "59000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Denmark",
    "Sales": "57000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Austria",
    "Sales": "38900"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Portugal",
    "Sales": "34000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Finland",
    "Sales": "31000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Poland",
    "Sales": "25000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Iceland",
    "Sales": "11900"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Greece",
    "Sales": "8300"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Turkey",
    "Sales": "7540"
  },
];

chartOptions = [{
  "captions": [{
    "Germany": "Germany",
    "UK": "UK",
    "France": "France",
    "Norway": "Norway",
    "Sweden": "Sweden",
    "Italy": "Italy",
    "Netherlands": "Netherlands",
    "Belgium": "Belgium",
    "Spain": "Spain",
    "Switzerland": "Switzerland",
    "Denmark": "Denmark",
    "Austria": "Austria",
    "Portugal": "Portugal",
    "Finland": "Finland",
    "Poland": "Poland",
    "Iceland": "Iceland",
    "Greece": "Greece",
    "Turkey": "Turkey",
  }],

  "color": [{
    "Germany": "#483D8B",
    "UK": "#483D8B",
    "France": "#483D8B",
    "Norway": "#008B8B",
    "Sweden": "#2F4F4F",
    "Italy": "#483D8B",
    "Netherlands": "#2F4F4F",
    "Belgium": "#2F4F4F",
    "Spain": "#2F4F4F",
    "Switzerland": "#008B8B",
    "Denmark": "#008B8B",
    "Austria": "#008B8B",
    "Portugal": "#2F4F4F",
    "Finland": "#483D8B",
    "Poland": "#2F4F4F",
    "Iceland": "#008B8B",
    "Greece": "#2F4F4F",
    "Turkey": "#483D8B",
  }],
  "xaxis": "Country",
  "yaxis": "Sales"
}];

function addCustomLegend(legendData) {
  var legend = d3.select("#legend")
    .selectAll(".legend-item") // Add class selector
    .data(legendData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend-item") // Add class
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
    });

  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    });

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.label;
    });
}
```

```css
#chart text {
  fill: black;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}

.axis text {
  font: bold 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis text.x-axis-label {
  font: bold 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #ffffff);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

#chart-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#chart-title h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #333;
}

#chart {
  width: 100%;
}

#legend {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  top: 100px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-title">
  <h2>2022 Electric Vehicle Sales in Europe</h2>
</div>
<div id="chart" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
<svg id="legend" width="200" height="200"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var salesData;
var runningData;
var runningColors;

var customLegendData = [{
    label: "Population: >10 Million",
    color: "#008B8B",
    lowerRange : 0,
    upperRange : 10000000
  },
  {
    label: "Population: 10 Million - 50 Million",
    color: "#2F4F4F",
     lowerRange : 10000000,
     upperRange : 50000000
  },
  {
    label: "Population: 50 Million - 100 Million",
    color: "#48308B",
    lowerRange : 50000000,
    upperRange : 100000000
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  Plot();
  addCustomLegend(customLegendData);
  attachLegendToggle();
});

function Plot() {
  TransformChartData(chartData, chartOptions);
  BuildBar("chart", chartData, chartOptions);
}

function BuildBar(id, chartData, options, level) {
  d3.select("#" + id).select("svg").remove();
  var chart = d3.select("#" + id);

  var margin = {
      top: 10,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 70,
      left: 70
    },
    barWidth = 70,
    barPadding = 5;
  var width = (barWidth + barPadding) * runningData.length; // Adjusted the width
  var height = $(chart[0]).outerHeight() - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var xVarName;
  var yVarName = options[0].yaxis;

  xVarName = options[0].xaxis;

  var xAry = runningData.map(function(el) {
    return el[xVarName];
  });

  var yAry = runningData.map(function(el) {
    return el[yVarName];
  });

  var capAry = runningData.map(function(el) {
    return el.caption;
  });

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(xAry).rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

  var yMax = d3.max(runningData, function(d) {
    return +d[yVarName];
  });
  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, yMax]).range([height, 0]);

  var rcolor = d3.scale.ordinal().range(runningColors);

  chart = chart
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var bars = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(runningData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "bar " + d[xVarName]; // Add a class based on the country
    })
    .attr("data-country", function(d) {
      return d[xVarName]; // Add data attribute with the country name
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (x(d[xVarName]) + barPadding / 2) + ", 0)";
    });

  var ctrtxt = 0;

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(xAry.length)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      var mapper = options[0].captions[0];
      return mapper[d];
    });

  var yAxisTicks = [0, 10000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000]
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickValues(yAxisTicks);

  bars.append("rect")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "bar-" + d[xVarName]; // Add a class based on the country
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(parseInt(d[yVarName]));
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(parseInt(d[yVarName]));
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - barPadding)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return rcolor(d[xVarName]);
    });

  bars.append("text")
    .attr("x", x.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(parseInt(d[yVarName])) - 5;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d[yVarName];
    })
    .attr("class", "bar-text");

  chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

  chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", -40)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

  return chart;
}

function attachLegendToggle() {
  d3.selectAll("#legend .legend-item").on("click", function(event, d) {
    var country = d.label;
    var barsToToggle = d3.selectAll("#chart [data-country='" + country + "']");

    barsToToggle.classed("hidden", function() {
      var isHidden = d3.select(this).classed("hidden");
      return !isHidden;
    });
  });
}

function TransformChartData(chartData, opts, level, filter) {
  var result = [];
  var resultColors = [];
  var counter = 0;
  var hasMatch;
  var xVarName;
  var yVarName = opts[0].yaxis;

  xVarName = opts[0].xaxis;

  for (var i in chartData) {
    hasMatch = false;
    for (var index = 0; index < result.length; ++index) {
      var data = result[index];

      if (data[xVarName] == chartData[i][xVarName]) {
        result[index][yVarName] = result[index][yVarName] + chartData[i][yVarName];
        hasMatch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (hasMatch == false) {
      ditem = {};
      ditem[xVarName] = chartData[i][xVarName];
      ditem[yVarName] = chartData[i][yVarName];
      ditem["caption"] = opts[0].captions != undefined ? opts[0].captions[0]
        [chartData[i][xVarName]] : "";
      ditem["title"] = opts[0].captions != undefined ? opts[0].captions[0]
        [chartData[i][xVarName]] : "";
      ditem["op"] = 1;
      result.push(ditem);

      resultColors[counter] = opts[0].color != undefined ? opts[0].color[0]
        [chartData[i][xVarName]] : "";

      counter += 1;
    }
  }
  runningData = result;
  runningColors = resultColors;
  return;
}


var chartData = [{
    "Country": "UK",
    "Sales": "370000",
    "Population":60000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "France",
    "Sales": "340000",
    "Population":70000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Norway",
    "Sales": "166000",
     "Population":6000000
    
  },
  {
    "Country": "Sweden",
    "Sales": "163000",
    "Population":11000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Italy",
    "Sales": "114000",
    "Population":80000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Netherlands",
    "Sales": "107000",
    "Population":12000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Belgium",
    "Sales": "97000",
    "Population":13000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Spain",
    "Sales": "82000",
    "Population":14000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Switzerland",
    "Sales": "59000",
     "Population":7000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Denmark",
    "Sales": "57000",
     "Population":8000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Austria",
    "Sales": "38900",
     "Population":9000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Portugal",
    "Sales": "34000",
    "Population":15000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Finland",
    "Sales": "31000",
    "Population":90000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Poland",
    "Sales": "25000",
    "Population":16000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Iceland",
    "Sales": "11900",
     "Population":6500000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Greece",
    "Sales": "8300",
    "Population":95000000
  },
  {
    "Country": "Turkey",
    "Sales": "7540",
     "Population":96000000
  },
];

chartOptions = [{
  "captions": [{
    "Germany": "Germany",
    "UK": "UK",
    "France": "France",
    "Norway": "Norway",
    "Sweden": "Sweden",
    "Italy": "Italy",
    "Netherlands": "Netherlands",
    "Belgium": "Belgium",
    "Spain": "Spain",
    "Switzerland": "Switzerland",
    "Denmark": "Denmark",
    "Austria": "Austria",
    "Portugal": "Portugal",
    "Finland": "Finland",
    "Poland": "Poland",
    "Iceland": "Iceland",
    "Greece": "Greece",
    "Turkey": "Turkey",
  }],

  "color": [{
    "Germany": "#483D8B",
    "UK": "#483D8B",
    "France": "#483D8B",
    "Norway": "#008B8B",
    "Sweden": "#2F4F4F",
    "Italy": "#483D8B",
    "Netherlands": "#2F4F4F",
    "Belgium": "#2F4F4F",
    "Spain": "#2F4F4F",
    "Switzerland": "#008B8B",
    "Denmark": "#008B8B",
    "Austria": "#008B8B",
    "Portugal": "#2F4F4F",
    "Finland": "#483D8B",
    "Poland": "#2F4F4F",
    "Iceland": "#008B8B",
    "Greece": "#2F4F4F",
    "Turkey": "#483D8B",
  }],
  "xaxis": "Country",
  "yaxis": "Sales"
}];

function addCustomLegend(legendData) {
  var legend = d3.select("#legend")
    .selectAll(".legend-item") // Add class selector
    .data(legendData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend-item") // Add class
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
    });

  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    })
    .on("click",function(data){
     console.log(data)
     let updattedChartData = chartData.filter((el => el.Population >= data.lowerRange && el.Population <=data.upperRange))
    TransformChartData(updattedChartData, chartOptions);
    BuildBar("chart", updattedChartData, chartOptions);
    });

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.label;
    })
      .on("click",function(data){
     console.log(data)
     let updattedChartData = chartData.filter((el => el.Population >= data.lowerRange && el.Population <=data.upperRange))
    TransformChartData(updattedChartData, chartOptions);
    BuildBar("chart", updattedChartData, chartOptions);
    });
    
}
```

```css
#chart text {
  fill: black;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}

.axis text {
  font: bold 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis text.x-axis-label {
  font: bold 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #ffffff);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

#chart-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#chart-title h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #333;
}

#chart {
  width: 100%;
}

#legend {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  top: 100px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-title">
  <h2>2022 Electric Vehicle Sales in Europe</h2>
</div>
<div id="chart" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
<svg id="legend" width="280" height="80"></svg>
```

> Note : You are using an outdated version of D3.js, and your code appears to be disorganized. There is room for improvement in creating a more organized and efficient code for a simple bar chart.